# "Unbalanced calls to begin/end" message after using UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, viewcontroller

Environment: iOS7/8, XCode6

ViewController_A (embedded in NavController_A) segues to ViewController_B (embedded in NavController_B), then ViewController_B unwinds back to ViewController_A. 
The segue from A to B is "modal" and "animated" with the presentation set to "current context" and the transition set to "default"

This works fine. 
However, if I open UIImagePickerController from ViewController_B via [self presentViewController], then cancel it, then unwinding from ViewController_B back to ViewController_A throws "Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for

More details:
In ViewController_B (conforms to UIImagePickerControllerDelegate) a button opens up ActionSheet with the options to select an image or take a photo. Tapping "select from lib" calls the method below:

```
- (void) selectPhoto
{
    UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    picker.delegate = self;
    picker.allowsEditing = YES;
    picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:nil];    
}
```

I did a lot of research and know what can cause this message, but have not been able to pinpoint the exact reason so far.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Are you push from ViewController_A to ViewController_B?

Comment: No, it is a modal segue